# Switching to activity after the button animation is played

Tags: java, android

The code below adds a Scale animation for the button.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Animation animScale = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scale);
        Button btnScale1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnScale1.setOnClickListener(view -> view.startAnimation(animScale));
```

I need to switch to another activity after playing the animation. I'm trying to build the logic as follows:

```
animScale.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animScale) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, p1.class);
                startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Android Studio outputs Implementation Methods in the line new Animation.AnimationListener()

Full code:

```
package en.my.voicechat;
 
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
 
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
 
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 
        //implementation of animation for each button
        final Animation animScale = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scale);
        Button btnScale1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btnScale1.setOnClickListener(view -> view.startAnimation(animScale));
 
        Button btnScale2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btnScale2.setOnClickListener(view -> view.startAnimation(animScale));
 
        Button btnScale3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btnScale3.setOnClickListener(view -> view.startAnimation(animScale));
 
        Button btnScale4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);
        btnScale4.setOnClickListener(view -> view.startAnimation(animScale));
 
        Button btnScale5 = findViewById(R.id.button5);
        btnScale5.setOnClickListener(view -> view.startAnimation(animScale));
 
        Button btnScale6 = findViewById(R.id.button6);
        btnScale6.setOnClickListener(view -> view.startAnimation(animScale));
 
        Button btnScale7 = findViewById(R.id.button7);
        btnScale7.setOnClickListener(view -> view.startAnimation(animScale));
 
        //attempt to apply the transition to Activity for the seventh button
        animScale.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animScale) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, p7.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not overriding the other interface methods maybe? (onAnimationStart, onAnimationRepeat)

Not really sure, it should state what's the issue is if you move your cursor above the code.

Like this:

```
animScale.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animScale) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, p7.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    }
            
    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {        
    }
});
```

Comment: Implement Methods. Probably, to figure it out, it's better to lay out the full code: https://pastebin.com/BpVpRPCK

Comment: @AnatolijRojs edited my answer to include the code snippet